# How to configure the speed option in my accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, duration, jsfiddle

I have created a script to make my div expandable.

```
$('.expandable').find('h2').on('click', function(){
      $(this).parent().css({height: (parseInt($(this).parent().css('height')) > 50)?'25px':'auto'});
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-plus-sign icon-minus-sign', 300);
  })
```

How can i configure the speed or duration of my div expandable, i want it going down slower and smoothly.

Thanks

Here my [accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/JSG9A/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/):

```
$('.expandable').find('h2').on('click', function(){
      $("#myList").slideToggle('slow');
})
```

Add an id to the list so we can find it easy:

```
<ul id="myList">
```

And hide it from start with css:

```
#myList {
    display: none;
}

/* And remove the height on the div */
.expandable{
    /*height: 25px;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

See updated: http://jsfiddle.net/JSG9A/2/

Comment: Grazie Mario! Ottima soluzione

Answer (score 0):

Use `animate` instead of `css` to change the height:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/